# Paper Clip Not Saving alternate styles

Tags: ruby-on-rails, imagemagick, paperclip

Paperclip is not saving any changes in the uploaded images but is saving original perfectly well. MY understanding from all the logs is that it cannot access ImageMagick... I have install RMagick along with paperclip. Somehow cannot find why is this happening? Can someone help me with how to check is paperclip is able to access ImageMagick.

Model:

```
has_attached_file :photo,
  :style => {
    :original => "500x500",
    :small => "200x200"
  }

attr_accessible :name, :photo
attr_protected :photo_file_name, :photo_content_type, :photo_size
```

gemfile:

```
gem 'paperclip', '2.3.16'
gem 'rmagick'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stupid Mistake!!!

```
:style => {
```

should be

```
:styles => {
```

Sorry for bothering!

Comment: Nice! Be sure to accept your own answer, so others can find it easily.